# Adding new tables in Nop Commerce2.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I want to add new features to the nop commerce 2.3 solution.

I have added new tables in the database and tried to insert data into it from the admin panel but I am unable to do so.

Comment: show the code that you used to insert the data, show the code you wrote for the admin view, and the server side code, so someone can get an idea where and what might go wrong.

Comment: This can be closed as Too Broad or Unclear.